# How to create a new array at occurrence of specific string ? numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

I have character delimited files which have different sets in the file

**File**

```
@Set 1  
0,1,2,3  
2,3,4,5  
.  
.  
@Set 2  
3,4,5,6  
4,5,6,7  
.  
.
```

I want to make arrays with data from each set and I will also need from which set the data is taken. I am using

```
with open('File', 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    numbers = []
    for line in f:
        ln = line.strip()
        if '@Set' in ln:
            data[ln] = numbers
            numbers = []
        elif ln:
            numbers.append([float(n) for n in ln.split(',')])
```

I can see `data['@Set 1']` but I am not able to use specific columns, and I want to use `numpy.genfromtxt` because I will need arrays where I can access columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('File', 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    numbers = []
    for line in f:
        ln = line.strip()
        if '@Set' in ln:
            data[ln] = numbers
            numbers = []
        elif ln:
            numbers.append([float(n) for n in ln.split(',')])
```

Each `numbers` should be a list of lists of floats.  Passing each through `np.array` should convert them to 2d arrays.

```
for k,v in data.items():
    data[k] = np.array(v)
```

To use `genfromtxt` take advantage that it works with any input that feeds it lines

```
with open('File', 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    numbers = []
    for line in f:
        ln = line.strip()
        if '@Set' in ln:
            data[ln] = numbers
            numbers = []
        elif ln:
            numbers.append(ln)

for k, v in data.items()
    data[k] = np.genfromtxt(v, ...)
```

There are other ways you could feed a set of lines to `genfromtxt`, but this was the simplest that I could write without glaring errors and need of testing.  In Python3 you may have to use the `rb` file mode.

I often test answers with code like:

```
txt = b"""1.23,2,3
4.34,5,6
""".splitlines()
data = np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see i dont need genfromtxt if I can convert them to numpy arrays. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `np.genfromtxt` with this file's format. Once you have the list `numbers` you can convert into `np.array` with:

```
import numpy as np
numbers_array = np.asarray(numbers)
```

so you can use specific columns as you want.

Comment: yeah, I modified my snippet and used it to do the same but there is a problem I am getting the last set first in dict.

Comment: np.asarray works only for 1D lists for 2D lists you can use np.array(data['@Set 1'])